# Unable to connect to kafka from druid

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

I have deployed druid in a kubernetes cluster.
I have kafka on pulsar(KOP) deployed in the same cluster but a different namespace.
I am able to produce and consume messages from the kafka topic via kafka client.
Document reference: https://medium.com/@sherlockxu/pulsar-on-kubernetes-enabling-kafka-on-pulsar-kop-with-pulsar-operators-27e3552c7ed8

In the broker end point I have given the hostname something like "pulsar-broker-0.pulsar.svc.cluster.local:9092"

I am not able to connect to kafka using the same hostname from druid.
The advertised listeners are set correct is what I am assuming. Because I am able to connect to kafka via client.

How am I connecting to kafka?
In druid click on Load Data ---> Select Apache kafka ---> Provide bootstrap server and topic name.
pulsar-broker-0.pulsar.svc.cluster.local:9092, test_topic and click on connect. After around 15 min I get 504